# How can you run Azure .Net SDK 1.7.1 with the current 1.7 local development storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to use the Azure .Net SDK version 1.7.1 from Github here (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1) with the local development storage.  There are some great features in the 1.7.1 SDK that I would like to use, however as soon as I used 1.7.1 DLL with my project, the tests that I had running against local dev storage, began failing with 400 - Bad Header error upon first access. After much effort, I figure out that changing the x-ms-version from "2012-02-12" to "2011-08-18" here:

In Constants.cs:

```
    internal const string TargetStorageVersion = "2011-08-18";
```

This got rid of the first problem, but now the GetBlobList with UseFlatBlobListing = true now fails with an error.  Does this just not work with the 1.7 local dev storage? Or, is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know you can't. Features available in the latest release of REST API (version 2012-02-12) like async copy blob, lease etc. are not supported by the storage emulator yet.

Comment: Thank you.  Was there a place that I could have seen this that I missed (just for future reference)?  Also, do you have any idea when the storage emulator will be updated?  Is the emulator on GitHub as well?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is mentioned anywhere. I also found out by trial-and-error. I'm not 100% sure as to when the latest changes will be rolled into SDK but Windows Azure Storage team is working on SDK 1.8. Hopefully these changes should be reflected in that SDK. You can watch a video of the same on Cloud Cover Show: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-84-Windows-Azure-Storage-Updates-and-the-New-Client-Library. Also I don't think Storage Emulator is on GitHub. Storage Client library obviously it. Hope this helps.